# ExtJS 4 : How to animate a sprite component using Ext.fx.Animator?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I've multiple sprite in my view, i want to make an animation to that sprite using Ext.fx.Animator to My Header component, but I get stuck how to do that.
This's my Sprite component:

```
var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
    items: [{
        type: "text",
        text: "Bla... Bla... Bla...",
        fill: "white",
        font: "18px monospace"
    }]
});
```

This is my Header :

```
Ext.define('APP.view.Header', { 
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'appHeader',
    dock: 'top',
    baseCls: 'app-header',

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.applyIf(this, {
            html: 'I want to place my sprite in here'
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

My problem is :

1. Can I use Ext.fx.Animator to control Opacity my sprite ? How to ?
2. How to make my sprite walking left to right and the other way ?

How to do that ?
May be somebody know about that ? I've search this over on google but no luck finding a way to do that.

Comment: Take a look at the Ext.dom.Element class in the docs and the animate() function.

Comment: I've read that, and the example. but how to apply the animation using fx.animator to a sprite i've created ? So I can modify animation  dynamically to every single sprite i have.